# Form validation on submit and on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a function that validate my inputs on the focusout event, but when I submit the form I need that the form be validated again, how can I do that? if I try this:

```
 $("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         if (validar()){
           $.ajax({
               blablablabla
           });
        }
    });
```

He throws that `input` is `undefined` I need to validade the form on the submit event cause the user can click directly on the submit button, this way, the function that make the form validation isn't executed.

```
function validar(input) {
 var valido = false;
  if(input.attr("id") === "email"){
      var filtro = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
      if(filtro.test(input.val())){
          input.css("border-color", "green");
      } else {
          input.css("border-color", "red");
          valido = false;
      }
  }
  else if (input.val()===""){
    input.css("border-color", "red");
    valido = false;
  }
  else if (input.val()!="") {
    input.css("border-color", "green");
  }

  return valido;
}

$("input[type='text'],textarea").focusout(function() {
  validar($(this))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `validar` function accepts a jQuery collection that contains for input field as an argument. One way to accomplish this based on the code your attempt could be something like this:

```
 $("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
        var input = $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea");
        event.preventDefault();
         if (validar(input)){
           $.ajax({
               blablablabla
           });
        }
    });
```

Another simple way to accomplish your end goal is to disable the submit button by default. For example:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="My Input Submit" disabled/>
```

You can then modify your `validar` function to return `true` for `valido` if the input is valid. This way you can use the return value to determine whether the submit button should be enabled. For example:

```
function validar(input) {
  var valido = true; // lets assume its valid to start with
  if(input.attr("id") === "email"){
      var filtro = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
      if(filtro.test(input.val())){
          input.css('border-color', 'green');
      } else {
          input.css('border-color', 'red');
          valido = false;
      }
  }
  else if (input.val()===''){
    input.css('border-color', 'red');
    valido = false;
  }
  else if (input.val()!='') {
    input.css('border-color', 'green');
  }

  return valido;
}
```

You can then use the use the return value in your `focusout` event handler to enable the button if the form is valid like so:

```
$('input[type="text"],textarea').focusout(function() {
  var isValid = validar($(this));
  if (isValid) {
    $('#formcontato').find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: I really liked the first option, but if only one of those inputs are valid and i click on the submit button he understand that every input is valid, there's a way to go through all the inputs for exemple, if i click on the submit button he pass through all the inputs and return if its valid of not, but if I just focus out my input he will validate only that input.